# C++ Decorator Pattern implementation with Arrays

Tags: c++, design-patterns, implementation, decorator

I have implemented Decorator pattern in C++ as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
using namespace std;

// Abstract Component
template <class T>
class IArray 
{
public:
   virtual void insert(const T&) = 0;
   virtual ~IArray(){}

};

// Concrete Component
template <class T>
class Array : public IArray<T>
{
public:
   virtual void insert(const T& elem)
   {
      m_array.push_back(elem);
   }

private:
   deque<T>   m_array;
};

// Decorator 1
template <class T>
class PositiveArray : public IArray<T>
{
public:
   PositiveArray(IArray<T>* component):m_component(component)
   {

   }

   virtual void insert(const T& elem)
   {
      if (elem > 0)
      {
         m_component->insert(elem);
      }
      else
      {
         cerr << "You can't insert non-positive number." <<endl;
      }
   }
private:
   IArray<T>*   m_component;
};


// Decorator 2
template <class T>
class PrintArray : public IArray<T>
{
public:
   PrintArray(IArray<T>* component):m_component(component)
   {

   }

   virtual void insert(const T& elem)
   { 
      m_component->insert(elem);
      cout << "Element " << elem << " was inserted into the array." <<endl;
   }
private:
   IArray<T>*   m_component;
};

// Client
int main()
{
   typedef int MyType;

   PositiveArray<MyType> arr(new PrintArray<MyType>(new Array<MyType>));
   arr.insert(10);
   arr.insert(-10);

   int i;
   cin>>i;
   return 0;
}
```

Now I want to have for all arrays `printArray` function. Should I write it as a pure virtual function in IArray and copy the following implementation of that function in each child of IArray?

```
   void printArray()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < m_array.size(); ++i)
      {
         cout << "elem " <<i << " is " << m_array[i] <<endl;
      }
   }
```

Is there any solution that can avoid of copying?

Answer (score 0):

I would implement `for_each_element` in either `Array`, and expose the interface in `IArray`.  It has 2 overloads that take `std::function< void(T const&) >` and `std::function< void(T) >` (second one is optional).  Now `PrintArray` is a one line lambda function.

In C++03 you can use `boost::function`, and `PrintArray` is more annoying to write.  So here it is less tempting.

As another approach, expose `const_iterator`s to the underlying data.

As an aside, `deque` performance is surprisingly poor.  As yet, there is nothing in your code that would make me think you could not use a `std::vector`.  If you guaranteed memory contiguity, you could even have your `const_iterator`s be `T const*` and expose the interface directly from `IArray` (with the implementation in `Array`).  `for_each_element` becomes a two-liner in C++11, and `PrintArray` even without C++11 or `for_each_element` is 2 lines, and either implemented inline in `IArray` or as a free function.

Oh, and I'd make `PrintArray` a free function rather than a member function.  `for_each_element` may need to be a member function, but you should be able to `PrintArray` without access to private data, once you expose iterators and/or `for_each_element`.

Comment: Could you write the code of solution by using old C++ standard?

Comment: Which solution?  `std::vector` and `typedef T const* const_iterator` and `virtual const_iterator begin()` is easy to write using C++03, and would be quite fast.  Using `for_each_element` in C++03 sucks compared to C++11, but you can do it via manual functors, or some boost libraries (lambda, phoenix, etc).  In 03, I'd be tempted to say my arrays are guaranteed to be contiguous, and use `typedef const T* const_iterator`.